# Error when calling approve function from a button

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, metamask

I have these 2 functions

```
function getData() {
  var a = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var b = a * 0.1;
  var c = a - b;
  document.getElementById("receive").innerHTML = c;
};

function approve(){
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // We are in the browser and metamask is running.
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider.enable());
}
  var accounts= web3.eth.getAccounts();
  var a = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var agiContract = new web3.eth.Contract(agiabi,agiContractAddress);
  agiContract.methods.approve("0xE462CbEE0cd420f6c199B0194B1D8D93Fb5e7720", a).send({ from: accounts[0] });
};
```

The function getData is getting an input amount from the User and this input amount is than passed into function approve():

With the approve function I'm getting this amount approved from a different contract so I can use the amount in my Contract.

But when I click approve I get this error:

```
web3.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.provider[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function
    at t.u.send (web3.min.js:1)
    at h (web3.min.js:1)
    at M.r [as getAccounts] (web3.min.js:1)
    at approve (exchange.js:84)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM15448 :227)
```

I used following versions of my function approve

```
function approve(){

  var accounts= web3.eth.getAccounts();
  var a = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var agiContract = new web3.eth.Contract(agiabi,agiContractAddress);
  agiContract.methods.approve("0xE462CbEE0cd420f6c199B0194B1D8D93Fb5e7720", a).send();
};
```

which gives me following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.
    at Object.d._executeMethod (web3.min.js:1)
    at approve (exchange.js:84)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM15481 :227)
```

What is the problem here?

I tried now this code but it is also not working

```
function getData() {
  var a = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var b = a * 0.1;
  var c = a - b;
  document.getElementById("receive").innerHTML = c;
};




function approve() {
      web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: web3.eth.coinbase,
        to: '0xE462CbEE0cd420f6c199B0194B1D8D93Fb5e7720',
        value: web3.utils.toWei(document.getElementById("amount").value, 'ether')
      }, function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
          console.log(result) ;
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
    }
```

This gives me

```
Uncaught Error: The send transactions "from" field must be defined!
    at f.inputTransactionFormatter (web3.min.js:1)
    at web3.min.js:1
```

I updated my code again

```
function getData() {
  var a = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var b = a * 0.1;
  var c = a - b;
  document.getElementById("receive").innerHTML = c;
};


function approve() {
  var accounts= web3.eth.getAccounts();

      web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts ,
        to: '0xE462CbEE0cd420f6c199B0194B1D8D93Fb5e7720',
        value: web3.utils.toWei(document.getElementById("amount").value, 'ether')
      }, function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
          console.log(result) ;
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
    }
```

and this gives me following error

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': #<Promise> could not be cloned.
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried to solve it?

Comment: From that error message given, you're either missing a parameter in the Contract method or giving an invalid one. Knowing why would mean sharing that function...You're asking people to solve a puzzle with missing pieces.

Comment: i dont see where im missing a parameter. approve is taking the contract that wants to use the token and the amount.  you can check out the whole thing here:
parallel-faucet.surge.sh only the approve button is hooked up, for the rest you ned console

Comment: https://imgur.com/mGCWzTt

The documentation disagrees.

Comment: how do I implement this?

Comment: and what has this to do with approve?

Comment: @DecipherMePlease can you please explain your answer? or please post a working example

Comment: question has been solved

Comment: @redbull you can write up the answer (or delete your question if you think it's not valuable to others). See [answer].